# On the union of algebraic sets

Tags: abstract-algebra

The definition of an algebraic set is given by:

> Let $S \subseteq k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$ be a set of polynomials. The *algebraic set* defined by S is $$
> V(S) = \{(a_1,a_2,...a_n) \in \mathbb{A}^n (k) : P(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)=0, \forall P \in S \}
> $$

Then I was asked to prove that given $X= V(f_1,..f_s)$ and $Y=V(g_1,...,g_t)$ are algebraic sets in $\mathbb{A}(k)$, then $X \cup Y$ is also an algebraic set.

My interpretation of the notation $X= V(f_1,..f_s)$ was that

$$X = \{(a_1,a_2,...a_n) \in \mathbb{A}^n (k) : f_i=0, i=1,...,s\}
$$

Then the solution I came up with was that $$
X \cup S = \{(a_1,...,a_n) \in \mathbb{A}^n(k) : f_ig_j = 0\}
$$

so it's an algebraic subset.
However, I'm not sure if this is the correct solution.

Comment: Assuming that by $f_i$ you mean $f_i(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and similarly for $g_j$, then yes, this seems correct.

Comment: @GregMartin ok yeah that's what I meant. So $X \cap Y$ would be $\{(a_1,...,a_n) \in \mathbb{A}^n(k) : f_i+g_j = 0\}$, right?

Comment: No, $X \cap Y$ would just be $\{ (a_1, \ldots, a_n) \in \Bbb A^n(k) \mid f_i=0 \land g_j=0 \}$.  Your proposal is too big:  What if $f_i=-g_j=1$ at some point?

Comment: @RobertShore what is the meaning of $f_i \land g_j$?

Comment: @mathripper The symbol is just a logical "and."

Comment: In other words, $V(f_1,\dots,f_s)\cap V(g_1,\dots,g_t) = V(f_1,\dots,f_s,g_1,\dots,g_t)$.